# How do I remove a SQL Server 2008 instance from command prompt w/o removing the server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to remove a SQL Server 2008 instance (just the instance, not the server). I know how to do it in SQL Server 2005, its

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\SetupBootstrap\setup.exe" /QUIET /qb REMOVE=SQL_Engine,Client_Components INSTANCENAME=<INSTANCENAME>
```

But I can't do the same in 2008. I tried:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2008R2\setup.exe" /QS /Action=Uninstall /FEATURES=SQLEngine /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESSAMEX
```

but it throws out:

> Error result: -2068643838
>   Result facility code: 1203
>   Result error code: 2

with this summary.txt:

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068643838
  Exit facility code:            1203
  Exit error code:               2
  Exit message:                  No feature were uninstalled during the setup execution. The requested features may not be installed. Please review the summary.txt logs for further details.
  Start time:                    2013-04-17 12:08:18
  End time:                      2013-04-17 12:08:53
  Requested action:              Uninstall

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  VPC01
  Machine processor count:       1
  OS version:                    Windows XP
  OS service pack:               Service Pack 3
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x86
  Process architecture:          32 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 
  Sql Server 2008 R2   SQLEXPRESS           MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS          Database Engine Services                 1033                 Express Edition      10.50.1600.1    No        
  Sql Server 2008 R2   SQLEXPRESS           MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS          SQL Server Replication                   1033                 Express Edition      10.50.1600.1    No        
  Sql Server 2008      SQLEXPRESSAMEX       MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESSAMEX         Database Engine Services                 1033                 Express Edition      10.1.2531.0     No        
  Sql Server 2008      SQLEXPRESSAMEX       MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESSAMEX         SQL Server Replication                   1033                 Express Edition      10.1.2531.0     No        
  Sql Server 2008                                                          Management Tools - Basic                 1033                 Express Edition      10.0.1600.22    No        

Package properties:
  Description:                   SQL Server Database Services 2008 R2
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2008 R2
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       10
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation edition:          EVAL

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Uninstall
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20130417_120805\ConfigurationFile.ini
  ENU:                           True
  FARMACCOUNT:                   <empty>
  FARMADMINPORT:                 0
  FARMPASSWORD:                  *****
  FEATURES:                      
  HELP:                          False
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  False
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              False
  INSTANCEID:                    <empty>
  INSTANCENAME:                  SQLEXPRESSAMEX
  PASSPHRASE:                    *****
  QUIET:                         False
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   True
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  X86:                           False

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20130417_120805\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

There are no scenario-specific rules.

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20130417_120805\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Exception summary:
The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
Inner exceptions are being indented

Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.NoopWorkflowException
    Message: 
        No feature were uninstalled during the setup execution. The requested features may not be installed. Please review the summary.txt logs for further details.
```

I think I'm just missing an option or some such, but I can't figure out what :P.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think "server" and "instance" are *different* in this context?

Comment: What was the date that your eval edition was installed? If it has expired, you are in for a rough time. You may want to see [this](https://sqlblog.org/2010/10/25/fun-with-software-uninstalling-sql-server-2008-r2-evaluation-edition). And to get it cleaned up, you may want to resign yourself to completely eradicating all SQL Server components and reinstalling without the eval (since certain components like Management Studio will expire, too, even after you remove the instance).

Comment: When I uninstall from add/remove programs I pull the 'Database Engine Services' and the 'SQL Server Replication' feature. Doing that leaves a bunch of SQL 2008 bits installed that I'd just as soon leave alone. You're right that instance and server are really the same here. Maybe I should have said 'Named Instance', but I'm not sure.

Comment: Sorry, using SQL Express (may the good lord help me). There shouldn't be an expiration. :P It's part of an application I'm writing.

Comment: Summary.txt says otherwise (`Installation edition: EVAL`).

Comment: Weird, and good catch, Maybe I'm using the wrong exe or something. There's several setup.exe's installed. One in Setup Bootstrap\Release and one in Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2008R2. When I run the uninstaller from add/remove programs it says 'Express' for the Edition though. I'll give the others a try

Comment: Found it: ### "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2008R2\setup.exe"  /Action=Uninstall /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /FEATURES=SQL,RS /QUIET ### The order of the parameters matters. If you put /QUIET first it breaks it. Also you can't just use SQLEngine as the top level feature to remove. You need to specify SQL & RS Thanks again!

Comment: I've found that sometimes I need to use the setup.exe in *\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2008R2 and sometimes the one in *\Setup Bootstrap\Release depending on how SQL 2008 was installed. What I'm not sure is why...

Comment: I tried through safe mode removing SQL server 2008 through programs and features it worked.

Answer (score 7):

Logging the answer from Jeremy's comments:

Found it:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2008R2\setup.exe" /Action=Uninstall /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /FEATURES=SQL,RS /QUIET
```

The order of the parameters matters. If you put /QUIET first it breaks it. Also you can't just use SQLEngine as the top level feature to remove. You need to specify SQL & RS.